# How to convert from c data into numpy object directly

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a python c extension now, I have some data in C++. Previously, I want to return data in Python native data type, so I can do this by calling Python C API. i.e. (PyLong_FromLong). However, now I want to also return data in numpy PyObject. Does anyone know how to convert a c++ double data into numpy's float64 PyObject?

Comment: Is this just one float value, or a whole array?  At least in Python code we rarely need to use `np.float64(1.234)`.  Instead we make an array, and may get such a float object by indexing, `x[0]`.  It might help if you provide more context, such as the use of `ctypes`, `cython`, `numba` or something else.

Comment: How familiar are you with the `NumPy C-API`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have already figured out that I need to use PyArray_Scalar inside https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/c-api.array.html